# Update disable product quantity programmatically in magento 2.1.X

Tags: magento-2.1

How to update disable product quantity programmatically.
Below code update product quantity which are in enable status.
Any one help me for this one.

Here is my code.

```
 public function updateStock($productId,$productQty)
{
    $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);

    if($product->getStatus() == 2){ // 2 => Disable , 1 => Enable

        $product->setStatus(1);

        if($product->getStatus() == 1){
            $product->setStockData([
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage product stock
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => $productQty 
            ]);

            $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus([
                'qty' => $productQty,
                'is_in_stock' => 1
            ]); 
        }

        $product->setStatus(2);

        try {
            $product->save(); 
            echo 'Quantity update of SKU => '.$product->getSku().'<br/>'; 
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getException();
        }

    }else{

        $product->setStockData([
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => 1, //manage product stock
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => $productQty
        ]);

        $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus([
            'qty' => $productQty,
            'is_in_stock' => 1
        ]); 

        try {
            $product->save(); 
            echo 'Quantity update of SKU => '.$product->getSku().'<br/>'; 
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the complete code. Update your question with full code

Comment: @SukumarGorai update my code. Full function add here. Check now my code.

Comment: @SukumarGorai This code update enable status product quantity properly; but not update disable status product quantity.

Comment: Are you getting any exception or error?

Comment: No, not generate any log or error regarding it.